# The Visual Studio Remote Debugger (MSMSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2017

When I want to debug my web project on local iis I get this error message. First I tried to debug an Umbraco project and I got the message below. First I thought it was because of Umbraco but a new empty web project gave the same error message.

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The Visual Studio 2017
>   Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the
>   remote computer. The may be because a firewall is preventing
>   communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance
>   on configuring remote debugging.

My configuration in Visual Studio 2017:

Local IIS

Project URL: http://my.domain.dev.nl

[image]

Virtual directory has been created successfully. Of course I tried some things before asking.

- I tried to restart the Remote Debugging process.
- I tried this command: devenv /resetuserdata.
- I started a complete new project.
- I changed debug CPU from any to x86 and x64 also.

If I choose for IIS Express I can run my project without any issues. 
Someone any idea?

**Edit:**

Another thing to mention is that I have tried to ping the local address *http://my.domain.dev.nl* and I got a reply from another ip. Of course I checked my IIS bindings but everything is ok.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164726(v=vs.140).aspx might be of help.

Comment: Of course I saw that page. When I ping my host I got a reply from an totally another ip